# Getting wrong output while counting inversions in an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

The problem is
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/

Inversion Count for an array indicates – how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If the array is already sorted, then the inversion count is 0, but if the array is sorted in the reverse order, the inversion count is the maximum.
Formally speaking, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j

Help me find what's wrong/missing in my code after reading the article. I am using the mergeSort technique here.

My code is:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int merge(vector<int>& nums, int start, int mid, int end){
    int count = 0;
    int n1 = mid - start + 1;
    int n2 = end - mid;
    vector<int> leftArray(n1);
    vector<int> rightArray(n2);
    for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        leftArray[i] = nums[start + i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++){
        rightArray[i] = nums[mid + 1 + i];
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = start;
    while(i < n1 && j < n2){
        if(leftArray[i] <= rightArray[j]){
            nums[k++] = leftArray[i++];
        }
        else{
            nums[k++] = rightArray[j++];
            count += (mid - i);
        }
    }
    while(i < n1){
        nums[k++] = leftArray[i++];
    }
    while(j < n2){
        nums[k++] = rightArray[j++];
    }
    return count;
}

int mergeSort(vector<int>& nums, int start, int end){
    if(start >= end) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    count +=  mergeSort(nums, start, mid);
    count += mergeSort(nums, mid + 1, end);
    count += merge(nums, start, mid, end);
    return count;
}

int countInversions(vector<int>& nums) {
    return mergeSort(nums, 0, nums.size() - 1);
    //return nums;
}
```

Comment: `count += (mid - i);` should be `count += (n1 - i);` .

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you very very much! I was struggling for hours to find out the error! Now it's working.

Comment: But why d u think it shouldnt be (mid - i) ?

Comment: If you are sorting a thousand-sized array, and merging two short sub-sequences somewhere towards the end - let's say `start==995, mid==997, end==999` - you are not eliminating 900+ inversions when you move an element from the right half two positions to the left. `mid - i` can't possibly be right since they are counting from different bases (`mid` is an absolute index counting from the beginning of the array; `i` is a relative index counting from `start`).